# How to start a mongodb service on mac OS X?

Tags: macos, mongodb

I have already installed Mongodb on my mac but the process is currently not running.
How do I start the Mongodb service so that I can start using the commands?

Comment: This depends on how you installed it. How did you install it?

Comment: try `mongod` in terminal

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Try the following steps in Terminal:

```
which mongod
```

This will output the path to your `mongod`, but if it is not in your `$PATH` the command output will be empty. So you need to find your executable:

```
find / -name 'mongod'
```

In the output of this command, you will see many lines, one of which will be like `bin/mongod`, e.g. `/usr/local/mongodb/bin/mongod`. In that case take the whole absolute path and do the following:

```
echo "PATH=/usr/local/mongodb/bin/:$PATH" >> ~/.bash_profile
. ~/.bash_profile
```

Then try again:

```
mongod --dbpath /your/path
```

Answer (score 79):

If you used homebrew to install MongoDB on macOS you type the following in terminal. Should do the trick in most cases.

```
$ brew services start mongodb
```

Comment: And you can adapt configuration in `/usr/local/etc/mongod.conf`

Comment: I’d use sudo to start the service. I ran the above command and apps could never connect to my database. With sudo, everything works, and the service is running in the background.

Comment: If you installed the community edition, might need to use `brew services start mongodb-community`

Answer (score 28):

Just do `brew services start mongodb-community`. Example:

```
$ brew services list
Name              Status  User Plist
mongodb-community stopped      
$ brew services start mongodb-community
==> Successfully started `mongodb-community` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community)
```

Of course, depends on your installation. This is the typical brew install.

Answer (score 20):

As now is 2021 year, so start `mongodb` on Mac:

## Use `brew`

- `brew services start mongodb-community`

  - for installed by: `brew install mongodb-community`

similarly:

### for specify version

- `brew services start mongodb-community@4.2`

  - for installed by: `brew services install mongodb-community@4.2`

### only running not want bootable

the `start` means **start** and **enable start at launch/boot**

for only run currently, use `run`:

- `brew services run mongodb-community`

### check status

after start, check status use:

- `brew services`

## Manually

for **old version** `mongodb`, the command is `mongod`:

- Directly run: `mongodb`
- Run with config: `mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf`

  - the default config file path is: `/usr/local/etc/mongod.conf`
- Run with only pass some parameter:

  - with database path: `mongod --dbpath /data`

    - `/data` is common mongodb database path

Answer (score 5):

Just go into a folder where you want mongodb to store all the database files and run the command

`mongod --dbpath=.`

Comment: I tried using the mongod in the command terminal and it says '-bash: mongod: command not found', any idea why I am getting this?

Comment: @nshetty: yes, because `mongod` is not in your `$PATH`

Answer (score 4):

To start the mongodb, you should only have to run the "mongod" command on the terminal.

Comment: I tried using the mongod in the command terminal and it says '-bash: mongod: command not found' ? Very new to this, sorry if it is very basic.

Answer (score 4):

**Install and Run MongoDB with Homebrew**

Open the Terminal app and type

> brew update

After updating Homebrew

> brew install mongodb-community@4.0

After downloading Mongo, create the “db” directory. This is where the Mongo data files will live.
You can create the directory in the default location by running

> sudo mkdir -p /data/db

Make sure that the /data/db directory has the right permissions by running

> sudo chown -R `id -un` /data/db

Run the Mongo daemon, in one of your terminal windows run

> brew services start mongodb-community

This should start the Mongo server.
Run the Mongo shell, with the Mongo daemon running in one terminal, type **mongo** in another terminal window. This will run the Mongo shell which is an application to access data in MongoDB.
To exit the Mongo shell run quit()
To stop the Mongo daemon hit ctrl-c

start service:

> brew services start mongo

https://treehouse.github.io/installation-guides/mac/mongo-mac.html

Answer (score 3):

For **mongodb-community@4.2**

**To start**
run *brew services start mongodb-community@4.2*

**To end**
run *brew services stop mongodb-community@4.2*

But if you don't know the specific version you could just omit the stating the version.

source: [Source](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/)

Answer (score 1):

Try with this following steps:

find your MongoDB path and MongoDB database path and run the below command

```
/Users/username/mongodb/bin/mongod --dbpath=/Users/username/mongodb-data/
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this line it will fix the issue.

Execute this line in your terminal at the mongo bin path:

```
export PATH=<mongodb-install-directory>/bin:$PATH
```

`<mongodb-install-directory>` replace this with your path, for example:

```
export PATH=/Application/Mongo/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: Better approach: https://medium.com/@saurabhkumar_4718/install-mongodb-without-homebrew-on-mac-os-2a98b68ab09c

Answer (score 0):

Check Installed Service Using:

```
brew services list
```

also can check directly using:

```
which mongod
```

Get Installed Service name and start service by name:

```
brew services start <service_name>
```

For Ex.

If Service name is mongodb

```
brew services start mongodb
```

If Installed community edition

```
brew services start mongodb-community
```

For specific version:

If mongodb-community@4.4 installed

```
brew services start mongodb-community@4.4
```