# brew services start mongodb-community@4.2 Error: Unknown command: services

Tags: mongodb, homebrew, macos-catalina

I am trying to run MongoDB by running `brew services start mongodb-community@4.2` but I am getting the error that you see below:

```
jaimes-mbp:SMR jaimemontoya$ brew services start mongodb-community@4.2
==> Tapping homebrew/services
Cloning into '/usr/local/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-services'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 27, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (27/27), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (19/19), done.
remote: Total 27 (delta 0), reused 16 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (27/27), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
Tapped 0 formulae (63 files, 276K)
Error: Unknown command: services
jaimes-mbp:SMR jaimemontoya$
```

Isn't `brew` the command, and `services` only a parameter? I am not understanding why the error says that `services` is an unknown command. Thank you.

**UPDATE 1:** I see two warnings when I try to run `brew install mongodb-community@4.2` again. Maybe that has something to do with the problem?:

```
jaimes-mbp:SMR jaimemontoya$ brew install mongodb-community@4.2
Warning: mongodb/brew/mongodb-community-4.2.3 already installed
Warning: You are using OS X 10.15.
We do not provide support for this pre-release version.
You may encounter build failures or other breakages.
```

**UPDATE 2:** When I use `mongo`, it is doing something:

```
jaimes-mbp:SMR jaimemontoya$ mongo
MongoDB shell version v4.2.3
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
2020-03-13T06:41:22.073-0600 E  QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:341:17
@(connect):2:6
2020-03-13T06:41:22.076-0600 F  -        [main] exception: connect failed
2020-03-13T06:41:22.076-0600 E  -        [main] exiting with code 1
jaimes-mbp:SMR jaimemontoya$
```

Maybe I do not need to use `brew services start mongodb-community@4.2`? I thought it was necessary to run MongoDB Community Edition.

**UPDATE 3:** I run `ps aux | grep -v grep | grep mongod` and it returns nothing. I am trying to verify that MongoDB is running, so I am searching for `mongod` in my running processes but it returns nothing, meaning that MongoDB is not running I guess.

**UPDATE 4:** See what happens when I run `brew doctor --verbose`:

```
Warning: You are using OS X 10.15.
We do not provide support for this pre-release version.
You may encounter build failures or other breakages.

Warning: Your Homebrew is outdated.
You haven't updated for at least 24 hours. This is a long time in brewland!
To update Homebrew, run `brew update`.

Warning: The /usr/local directory is not writable.
Even if this directory was writable when you installed Homebrew, other
software may change permissions on this directory. Some versions of the
"InstantOn" component of Airfoil are known to do this.
```

You should probably change the ownership and permissions of /usr/local
back to your user account.
  sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local

When I run `sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local`, I get this:

```
jaimes-mbp:SMR jaimemontoya$ sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local
Password:
chown: /usr/local: Operation not permitted
jaimes-mbp:SMR jaimemontoya$
```

`brew update` is not working:

```
jaimes-mbp:SMR jaimemontoya$ brew update
Error: The /usr/local directory is not writable.
Even if this directory was writable when you installed Homebrew, other
software may change permissions on this directory. Some versions of the
"InstantOn" component of Airfoil are known to do this.

You should probably change the ownership and permissions of /usr/local
back to your user account.
  sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local
jaimes-mbp:SMR jaimemontoya$
```

Comment: Does this solve your problem [How to start a mongodb service on mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31564526/how-to-start-a-mongodb-service-on-mac-os-x)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed the advice MikeMcQuaid provided at https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/3665:

> You need to uninstall and install Homebrew using
>   https://github.com/Homebrew/install

As explained at https://github.com/Homebrew/install, I first ran `/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"`. After that I ran `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"`.

Then I ran this:

```
jaimes-mbp:SMR jaimemontoya$ brew tap mongodb/brew
Updating Homebrew...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/core).
No changes to formulae.

==> Tapping mongodb/brew
Cloning into '/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/mongodb/homebrew-brew'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 86, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (86/86), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (76/76), done.
remote: Total 145 (delta 41), reused 21 (delta 10), pack-reused 59
Receiving objects: 100% (145/145), 30.18 KiB | 2.16 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (68/68), done.
Tapped 6 formulae (33 files, 83.0KB).
jaimes-mbp:SMR jaimemontoya$ brew install mongodb-community@4.2
==> Installing mongodb-community from mongodb/brew
==> Downloading https://fastdl.mongodb.org/osx/mongodb-macos-x86_64-4.2.3.tgz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Caveats
To have launchd start mongodb/brew/mongodb-community now and restart at login:
  brew services start mongodb/brew/mongodb-community
Or, if you don't want/need a background service you can just run:
  mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/mongodb-community/4.2.3: 21 files, 304.3MB, built in 1 minute 54 seconds
jaimes-mbp:SMR jaimemontoya$ brew services start mongodb-community@4.2
==> Tapping homebrew/services
Cloning into '/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-services'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 88, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (88/88), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (47/47), done.
remote: Total 691 (delta 31), reused 69 (delta 25), pack-reused 603
Receiving objects: 100% (691/691), 192.79 KiB | 1.68 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (270/270), done.
Tapped 1 command (39 files, 266.3KB).
==> Successfully started `mongodb-community` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community)
jaimes-mbp:SMR jaimemontoya$ ps aux | grep -v grep | grep mongod
jaimemontoya     17763   0.1  0.2  5544164  38300   ??  S     8:11AM   0:00.65 /usr/local/opt/mongodb-community/bin/mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf
jaimes-mbp:SMR jaimemontoya$
```

It works!

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you are facing issue with `brew`.

Run `brew doctor --verbose` to check if the brew is working fine.

And then `brew update` to update the brew version.

After this run, `brew services list` to display all the services in the brew.

If you see mongodb-community@4.2 there in the list, then run `brew services start mongodb-community@4.2`

It should work.

Comment: See my UPDATE 4. Apparently using OS X 10.15 is a problem, which is odd because it is the latest version of OS X and I upgraded because I thought the old version I had was the problem. The fact that my `/usr/local` directory is not writable seems to be a problem too.